# .NET SQL client stored procedure call empty statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

I have a .NET 6 C# app that calls three stored procedures on a SQL Server. Two of these calls work ok, but the third gives a null ref exception at the line:

> result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

```
using (var con1 = this.GetSqlConnection())
{
    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = OnlinePaymentCheckNurseryChildSProc;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        LogSqlParams(cmd.Parameters);
        con1.Open();

        result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        LogInfo(methodName, $"result=:{result}");

        LogInfo(methodName, $"Leaving:{methodName}");
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex, methodName, "Trouble checking nursery child");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The stored proc ends with:

```
 
        IF (@d = @DOB)
        BEGIN
               SET @Return = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
               SET @Return = 0
        END
 
        RETURN @Return
END
```

I've called the same stored procedure with the same parameters from SQL Server Management Studio and it works ok.

Comment: You seem to be calling the stored procedure twice - once with your `await command1.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` call (not taking care of the data being returned - if any), and then again a few lines down with `await command1.ExecuteReaderAsync();` - why twice??

Comment: @marc_s thanks for that. This code was developed by somebody else. I don't think it's ever worked. Now that you've pointed out the problem with the multiple calls to the stored proc I've updated the code to reflect what I have now. It sill drops into the block wit h the LogError i.e reader.HasRows is false

Comment: The statement block is empty because no statement happened; this is a direct RPC call to the sproc. If you want to capture the statement including parameters, capture "RPC:Starting". Though, if you have access to the code, it's easier to just set a breakpoint and inspect `params` at the point of call.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for that. So it seems the empty statement value was a red herring. I created a LogSqlParams method to get a view of them. They look to be perfect.

Comment: Have you checked the 'OnlinePaymentCheckNurseryChildSProc' variable when the statement is empty?

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri thanks for the suggestion but yes just double checked and that's set correctly

Comment: Are any of the parameters null? Maybe the procedure has default values and the proc is not using IsNull.

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri each of the 3 params is populated

Comment: You should update your question with the failing SP definition.

Comment: ok, stored proc now added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving this problem was to use the ExecuteNonQuery method and pass a special param with a "Direction" property of ParameterDirection.ReturnValue.

The working code block can be see below:

```
using (var con1 = this.GetSqlConnection())
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = OnlinePaymentCheckNurseryChildSProc;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        LogSqlParams(cmd.Parameters);
        SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter();
        returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
        con1.Open();
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        int result = (int)returnValue.Value;
        LogInfo(methodName, $"result=:{result}");

        LogInfo(methodName, $"Leaving:{methodName}");
        return result == 1 ? true : false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex, methodName, "Trouble checking nursery child");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh right. with the SP definition it get much easier, I think you would have had an answer much sooner. Because in fact the SP is not selecting anything - so the HasRows property is false.